# Getting GIF and/or moving images into a LaTeX presentation

Tags: beamer, graphics, animations, gif

I'm very new to presentations in LaTeX (I've been using PowerPoint for years but have finally converted).

I am wondering how to get a GIF into a section. If need be, I can convert a GIF into lots of pictures and have them overlay to give the impression of movement.

Comment: Yeah, if you mange to convert into "normal" pictures, than it is quite easy to include them with `\multiinclude`

Comment: How does one split my gif into images?

Comment: @iluvLatex ffmpeg is the easiest option. `ffmpeg -i input/Clap.gif -vsync 0 temp/temp%d.png` [source](https://www.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/comments/cqwlwo/comment/ex153rh/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Answer (score 145):

**1. Convert and split animated GIF into PNG sequence**

```
convert -coalesce something.gif something.png
```

or

```
magick convert -coalesce something.gif something.png
```

`convert`/`magick convert` is a command line tool from the ImageMagick.org software package. The command name depends on the software version.

This produces a set of numbered PNG files `something-0.png, ..., something-16.png` (Here, the original GIF https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHJmL.gif, renamed to `something.gif` consists of 17 frames.) Option `-coalesce` is necessary to undo a possible optimization of the original GIF file.

**2. Get original animation speed**

```
magick identify -verbose something.gif | grep 'Delay'
```

Users of Windows may want to run

```
magick identify -verbose something.gif | sls -Pattern 'Delay'
```

in the PowerShell.

This outputs lines (one for every frame) like:

```
Delay: 10x100
Delay: 10x100
Delay: 10x100
...
```

The frame rate (frames per second), to be passed as an argument to the `\animategraphics` command below, is found by dividing the number after `x` by the number in front of it:

*frame rate* = 100 (tics/s) / 10 (tics/frame) = 10 frames/s

**3. Embed PNG sequence as an embedded looping animation in the final PDF**

(This kind of animation requires a **JavaScript**-supporting PDF viewer, such as **Acrobat Reader** or **KDE Okular**.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Embedded Animation}
  \animategraphics[loop,controls,width=\linewidth]{10}{something-}{0}{16}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Argument `{10}` sets the desired frame rate (frames per second), `{0}` and `{16}` set the first and last file numbers of the PNG series to be included in the animation. Note that frame rates above 30 FPS, if at all achieved by the PDF viewer, do not make much sense. 30 FPS is a typical value in video encoding. Use command option **`measure`** and the <kbd>+</kbd> button to see which frame rates are possible. They may depend on the image size and of course on the hardware on which the PDF viewer is running.

For a more GIF-like impression, option `autoplay` can be used instead of or in addition to option `controls`.

[image]

Comment: I am unsure what gifsicle --unoptimize VHJmL.gif > something.gif
convert something.gif something.png does or how to use it.

Comment: `convert -coalesce ...` does the same like `gifsicle --unoptimize ...`. Thus, `gifsicle` is not needed.

Comment: @AlexG Thanks! Learned something new today! Than sorry for my misleading comment! -> I deleted them

Comment: I don't see the controls in the pdf. There is a hand cursor, but clicking does nothing.

Comment: I have the latest Adobe Reader DC.

Comment: @user4417 You will also need the most recent `animate` package version 2016/03/15 .

Comment: What is the `{12}` for?

Comment: @Annan : Frames per second.

Comment: Does LaTeX support APNG (Animated PNG)?

Comment: @Royi The question is rather: Does the PDF standard support APNG? The answer is 'No'. You must convert it into a series of images and use one of the suggested methods (multipage PDF or `animate`-based animation).

Comment: @AlexG, I see. Is there a reason it doesn't support? Is there a way to change that (Namely let those who set the standard know)? It is really limiting that PDF doesn't support APNG & videos out of the box.

Comment: The PDF format and its viewer are Adobe inventions. I think they still define and extend the standard, although PDF is now an ISO standard.

Comment: For someone else who stumbles upon this: The `{0}{16}` describes the first and last frame of the animation. You'll need to `identify something.gif` to determine how many frames are in the gif

Comment: in Ubuntu 16.04:  `mogrify -identify -verbose something.gif | grep 'Delay'`

Comment: Another observation: `identify -verbose something.gif | grep 'Delay'` is enough. In fact, prepending `magick` causes an error.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. As said, it depends on ImageMagick's version. For me both work.

Comment: `magick identify -verbose something.gif | sls -Pattern 'Delay'` doesn't work for me on Win10 with the last version of imagemagick. So, would you please edit your answer to calculate the framerate based on the delay that can be obtained as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14418469/2849383).

Comment: A true operating system independent way of getting ImageMagick is with docker. I used this container: https://hub.docker.com/r/dpokidov/imagemagick/. You don't even really need to understand docker to use it for this example.

Comment: @Diaa Command line as given works for me.

Comment: It doesn't work. I got one picture on a slide and it is not showing any animation in Okular. Using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Edit: It runs smoothly in Adobe reader in windows but then I will have to install adobe (2013 version, vulnerable) or use wine acrordrdc (display issues reported).

Comment: @praveenpathak : Works for me: Okular-21.04.2 with Poppler-21.05.0 . Check the Okular and Poppler versions. The OS version you mentioned doesn't tell anything about the PDF viewer version you are using.

Comment: @praveenpathak see edit: image replaced with Okular example.

Comment: @AlexG Okular version is 1.9.3 (21.04). I dont know how to check Poppler version. But I converted gif in mp4 and it is working properly in pdfpc and Pympress.

Comment: Are there free online websites that can convert these set of images to a javascript supporting pdf viewer?

Comment: I would do the conversion locally, with ImageMagick installed. On Windows, enter `cmd.exe` in the search/execute bar somewhere in the Start menue to open a command line window.

Comment: As of today (2021) this does not work on Windows 10 (with Adobre Reader DC or Okular). Clicking on the control bar doesn't launch the animation.

Comment: Which AR DC version do you use? (Help->About)

Answer (score 49):

Ok, let's start with the `.gif` from @SeanAllred comment.

**First Step: Converting**

There are probably many methods to do so. To be independent of the operation system, there are online converter, ask your favourite search engine for suggestions.

Or if you prefer using the command line use `convert` from ImageMagick:

```
convert -coalesce VHJmL.gif something.png
```

Make sure you resulting images are named `something-0` and so on.

**Second Step: multiinclude**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xmpmulti}
\begin{document}
    
    %asuming you images are called "something-0.png" up to "something-16.png" 
    \begin{frame}
        \transduration<0-16>{0}
        \multiinclude[<+->][format=png, graphics={width=\textwidth}]{something}
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/VHJmL.gif

Comment: I get errors because the pictures are of gif format

Comment: convert them vor example using http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-png

Comment: It (the PDF) doesn't loop :-(

Comment: @AlexG But the command line approach does :)

Comment: I think i can get the images into latex the way i want, however am having problems actually converting them in the first place.  As i have 84 picture in gif format conveting each is going to be a pain.

Comment: 84 different pictures or one animated gif with 84 frames. In the second case have a look at the command line approach, as it does all at once

Comment: I had 1 gif with 84 frames, I now have 84 different pictures in gif form. No idea what to do next

Comment: What operating system are you working on?

Comment: I get a slide per png file, but no animation. I can advance the "animation" myself, but then there are pauses and white screens.

Comment: Does LaTeX support APNG (Animated PNG)?

Comment: @Royi Probably not out of the box, but if you manage to convert it into a series of images you can use the same technique as in my answer above. PS comments are not a good place to ask new questions.

Comment: My experience: The `xmpmulti` approach seems to be much more demanding for the CPU than the `animate` approach, at least on my decent Windows machine. Meaning that the animation is not smooth.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner The `animate` approach is very smooth on Linux. Static, in fact. :(

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner On the other hand, this method is also static - there's just more that is static. :(

Comment: @cfr Being philosophical tonight :)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Occupational hazard.

Comment: How to control the speed?

Comment: @hengxin The speed is controlled by the value in `{..}` . `{0}` means that the animation is played as fast as the viewer can switch slides. If you want slower, increase the value. For example if the slides should only change every 10 seconds, use `{10}`

Comment: It does not work. I get one picture per slide.

Comment: It didn't work for me on Ubuntu 20.04. I got animation run on okular but it is very very slow, in fact almost static. I am using the option {0} for the fastest animation speed.

Comment: Why the animation speed is less in my pc than shown on yours? @samcarter

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at [pdfpc](https://github.com/pdfpc/pdfpc#sample-presentations) they have an [example](https://github.com/pdfpc/pdfpc/releases/latest/download/pdfpc-video-example.zip) how to embed videos. pdfpc is a tool for displaying your `beamer` presentations.

It doesn't work with `gif`s but you can still `convert something.gif something.avi`. To get a preview picture run `convert something.gif poster.png`

Updated example for using the `multimedia` package now recommended by `pdfpc`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multimedia}

\begin{document}
  \frame{
    \movie{\includegraphics{poster.png}}{movie.avi}
  }
\end{document}
```

Display your presentation with `pdfpc my-presentation.pdf`

In earlier versions it didn't seem to work if your video was in another directory set by `\graphicspath`.

Comment: Have done that: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444158/108331

Comment: Couldn't find pdfpc-commands.sty file. Can pdfpc-movie.sty be used instead?

Comment: @praveenpathak pdfpc seemed to changed some things since I wrote this answer. I edited to reflect these changes as best as I could.

Comment: Yes, this works now. Thank you @Benjamin

Comment: This also works with `Document Viewer` on Ubuntu LTS 20 when the PNG and AVI files are both in the working directory.