# How to add a GIF to beamer

Tags: beamer, animate

I'm new to latex, and I'm trying to add a .gif file to my beamer, I used the package `animate`, but it doesn't work, I keep getting the error `animate: Niether of the files`. Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\animategraphics[loop,autoplay]{6}{WT_t}{001}{143}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You cannot, gif is not supported by latex.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Getting Gif and/or moving images into a Latex presentation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240243/), but whether you use  `\multiinclude` or `\animategraphics`, it looks like your GIF should have already been broken into multiple PNG files. Have you converted your GIF into a set of static images?

Comment: According to your example code, the file sequence is named `WT_t001.png` , `WT_t002.png`, ... . Is this the case?

Comment: @AlexG, exactly.

Comment: @MikeRenfro? I have.

Comment: @ToneyShields Can you please post the `.log` file of your example?

Comment: Test, whether `\includegraphics{WT_t001.png}` works instead of `\animategraphics...`. Just to assure that files are in the search path...