# embed gif to latex-beamer?

Tags: beamer, png, gif, convert

I'm trying to embed the this GIF 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Bernstein_Approximation.gif
to beamer but I can't succeed. I converted GIF to the PNG but all websites convert that GIF wrongly (for ex. it looks like half picture), therefore such kind of codes doesn't work.

```
\animategraphics[loop,controls,width=\linewidth]{12}{something-}{0}{16}
```

So, I tried to embed as MP4 but it didn't work either. What can I do, how can I embed this GIF to the `beamer`. Could you help me please?

Comment: You could use imagemagick to convert the gif into png, see for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240247/36296

Comment: For aesthetic reasons, I'd rebuild this kind of plot as a vector graphics, using TikZ or pgfplots.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as the problem is the conversion of the .gif