# simple new way to use gif on beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, animations, movie15, multimedia, gif

I searched `stack` and `net` for use `gif` in beamer presentation. most of result are about at-least for two or three years ago. most of them used converted images, and some of them had serious problem with `frames`, `autoplay`, `footline` and so on.
now my question is after these years there is not a simple way to use `gif` in beamer presentation. if problem is with readers is there any `plugin` for reader softwares to handle this problem?

as you see this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240243/getting-gif-and-or-moving-images-into-a-latex-presentation) asked 2 years ago but still do not have best answer mark.

as matter of fact I hope there be a way that `\includegraphic` support `gif` or new command or package created to solve this issue.

using gif in presentation is very common today, and still hope developers who are joined this site pay much attention to it.

Comment: I don't think there is some miraculous new method. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/240243/36296 should still be the methods to go

Comment: Nothing has changed. (Animated) Gif is not supported by the PDF ISO standard. Thus, no one providing a PDF viewer will take the effort to also include a Gif viewer plugin, because it would target at non-conforming PDF files. Thus the methods presented in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/240243 may be the only options.

Comment: Unless PDF specifications change it will stay like this

Comment: @asys Well, take the effort and read the linked answers. They tell you about the commands and packages to be used. BTW, only the questioner may set the best-answer-mark. If others could do instead, they would have done, probably.

Comment: Is gif really so common today? I thought of gif death for some years now.

Comment: @samcarter sometimes we need to explain a process. let take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41221966/autonomous-seam-detection-in-images-on-matlab).
I think one animated tells better than lots of explain.

Comment: @asys Perfect example of when not to use `.gif`. Save the images individually and use either `multiinclude` or `animategraphics` to animate them in beamer. By storing them as .gif you loose quality which will be noticeable in things like your red line. (my personal opinion)

Comment: @samcarter : Quality is a very good point! Gif supports palettes of only 256 colours.