# Including a gif movie in overleaf

Tags: gif

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{movie15}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\includemovie[inline=false]{5cm}{5cm}{Monopole_anim.gif}
\end{document}
```

I have typed the above, the gif animation is here
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Aeroacoustics/Acoustic_Sources#/media/File:Monopole_anim.GIF

But nothing is shown on the preview page (it is not an error), just completely blank.

Comment: This might help you inserting animated gifs: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240387

Comment: But it would need me to change the document class to beamer. I have to use my current style (report) since I am including an animation in my group project.

Comment: No. Package `animate` works with any document class.

Comment: where should I add the line
convert -coalesce Monopole.gif Monopole.png ?

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/14116991zfbttpsgjsym#/54641567/

Comment: @carrie The `convert` command needs to be executed from the terminal on your local machine (the command is part of  ImageMagick). If you are using Overleaf, you need to upload all of the 30 frames to be able to use them inside your document.

Comment: @epR8GaYuh So is it impossible for me to add an animation if I don't have all frames?

Comment: No, it isn't impossible for you to do so. By using the `convert` command, you can extract all the frames from the GIF file to use them for your animation inside the document afterwards.

Comment: @epR8GaYuh Do you mean that, I first have to download a software called ImageMagick to extract all frames, then plug it into the Overleaf file I am currently working on with the code implemented above?

Comment: Yes, you have to download ImageMagick, install it to your local device, extract the frames with it on your local device, then upload the extracted frames to Overleaf.

Comment: See [↗ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/read/zxbnyqtwvhsy)