# Beamer animate package error

Tags: beamer, animations, animate

I'm generating an error when I try to run an animation in beamer.  I have a set of 100 png files titled 0.png, 1.png, etc.  Calling with this code,

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{a}
    \animategraphics[autoplay,loop]{20}{figs/animBending/}{0}{100}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I generate the error

```
libpng error: Not a PNG file
```

I've tried renaming all my files with extensions .png and .PNG, both give the same error.  What's the issue here?

Edit: .log file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-fPXffGHnoCBeDsqYDNS94oqPb-D7eQy/view?usp=sharing)

Edit: 0.png [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WDlV0L1EpVaUbDDSbMAQt8r4FzwAjiv_/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! I can't reproduce the error, it works for me.

Comment: Interesting. Never tested with files having a zero basename but just numbers.

Comment: I just tested and with pdflatex from texlive2017 it works fine for me.

Comment: Well, I tried a small set of files `0.png, 1.png, 2.png, 3.png` residing in a subfolder and had no problems either. Phew!!

Comment: Libpng obviously complains about your files. Could you try to look at them in some image processing software (e. g. ImageMagick)?

Comment: @AlexG I don't know much about command line software like that, I do all my TeXing through an IDE and never have to worry about it. Windows lists it as a png file though, and I can open it as such in any windows-based image programs that I try.

Comment: @avikarto one step back to make sure your images are OK. Does `\includegraphics{./figs/animBending/0}` and `\includegraphics{./figs/animBending/0.png}` work?

Comment: @samcarter Good call.  This also generates the error.  It must be that my files are screwed up, as AlexG suggested.

Comment: @avikarto the image you linked to seems to be a .gif and not a .png

Comment: @avikarto see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/240243/36296 for some suggestions how to convert an animated gif to png

Comment: @samcarter Per the post, I used imagemagick to split the gif into pngs, and now the individual image shows with includegraphics (thanks!).  However, with animategraphics, still only the first image shows.

Comment: Scratch that last.  The animation plays fine.  It simply wasn't showing up in the PDF reader I was using.

Answer (score 1):

The images in question were apparently gif files even though windows recognized them as .png.  This was the source of the errors.

Comment: Therefore: Never suppress showing the file endings in WindosExplorer. There must be a switch somewhere to configure this.

Comment: @AlexG I have windows set to show extensions, and the extensions are .png.  The tool I used to convert the images must have simply renamed files *.gif->*.png instead of converting for real.