# Animation not running in presentation made using beamer class

Tags: beamer, animations, animate

I wish to include an `.gif` animation in my latex beamer presentation. Based on my reading from various sources, including this website, what I understood was that I need to convert `.gif` into a series of `.jpg` images. I have converted `.gif` into 10 `.jpg` images titled from `foo-1.jpg` to `foo-10.jpg`. I have put all these images in the same folder where I have my template file and other images which are used subsequently. Next, I am using the below commands to include it as an animation

```
\begin{frame}    
\animategraphics{12}{foo-}{0}{10}
\end{frame}
```

On doing this, I get no error, but the slide is shown as given in the attached image. [image]

As it can be clearly seen, the animation does not fit on the slide, nor is it showing a set of moving images like a `.gif` file. What shall I do to get the animation nicely on the slide. I am ready to share all the 10 images if needed as a MWE, but please help me to overcome this problem.

Comment: Off-topic: for such an image with lines, png is much better suited than jpg

Comment: I even have .png images. but they are not working too. It is Latex beamer presentation, only that I wish to add animation in it. If there is an other technique to  do it,please tell

Comment: `\animategraphics[loop,controls,width=\linewidth]{12}{foo-}{0}{10}` or whatever width you want

Comment: to view it, you need a pdf viewer with of java script

Comment: or use https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240247/36296 which I personally find safer

Comment: Also off-topic, but your figure seems to be simple enough that it could be drawn with Ti*k*Z/pgfplots or pstricks.

Comment: @marmot, it is not a figure but an approximately 30 seconds long animation that shows how the blue graph changes as alpha varies. As a screenshot it looks like a picture

Comment: Which PDF viewer are you using?

Comment: Now, it runs fine after setting width as @samcarter told it. It has a play, pause option and one can manually go to the next picture also

Comment: @AlexG Adobe Acrobat Reader

Comment: Ok, AR is the right choice here.

Comment: Yes, but such things can be drawn in Ti*k*Z/pgfplots/pstricks. I am doing this all time. You just need to animate a parameter.

Comment: @samcarter. That question "Getting Gif..." had not solved the problem completely since I was having issues in getting a correct width. Though the rational used has been borrowed from the same question, but it alone was not sufficient in solving my problem, else I would not have posted this question again here

Comment: @ShiS Please feel free to write an answer to your question

Comment: @samcarter Done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the problem has been borrowed from the comment of @samcarter. The correct latex code used is as follows

```
\begin{frame}[t]
\animategraphics[loop,controls,width=8.5cm]{12}{foo-}{0}{20}
\end{frame}
```

Using the above code, the screenshot of the solution slide is given as follows:
[image]

As it can be seen, it is possible to play, pause and some other options are also there, which makes it look better in a presentation

Comment: It would look even better if you used a LaTeX-based plotting/graphing package such as `pgfplots` together with `animate`. As @marmot suggests, you will get high quality vector graphics which can be animated by animating a parameter.

Comment: @AlexG I don't  know about`pgfplots`package. If possible, please post an answer on how it can be done

Comment: Look for tagged questions, entering `[animate] [pgfplots]` in the search bar.