# How to create an animation from a 30-page PDF file?

Tags: beamer, pdf, animations, animate, gif

I've made a sequence of 30 vector graphics in one PDF file. (Each page of the PDF file contains one graphic). I want to make an animation and display it in a beamer presentation.

I've found an answer to a similar question in this forum which uses the "animate" package but it doesn't work for me I don't know why.

The code run without any error but the display is only a blank page.
I've tried to use "\includegraphics" just to be sure that the file is readable by the Texmaker and it displayed the first page of the PDF file.

This is my code (The file name is "CYCLE"):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}

\animategraphics[autoplay,loop,scale=0.35]{3}{CYCLE}{}{}


\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Which pdf viewer do you use? For `animate` based animations you need a pdf viewer capable of flash, such as adobe reader

Comment: I was using the PDF reader of the Texmaker and also the "impressive" reader but both of them can not read the animation.
Now, I tried with adobe acrobat reader and it worked Well. 
Thank you a lot. the problem was only with the software used to read the animation.
There is no way to use the advantages of impressive with an animation ?

Comment: Quote from the animate package documentation: "PDF files with animations can be viewed in Acrobat Reader (except on mobile devices), PDF-XChange and Foxit Reader."

Comment: I never used `impressive` myself, but in case it supports automatic slide transitions, you could try this technique: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240247/36296

Comment: @samcarter Flash is not a precondition, but JavaScript ;-)

Comment: @AlexG Damn, I keep mixing these two up. Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

Quote from the [↗Introduction](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf#section.1) of the `animate` package manual:

> PDF files with animations can be viewed in Acrobat Reader (except on
>   mobile devices), PDF-XChange and Foxit Reader.

Animations rely on [↗JavaScript for Acrobat](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/Acro12_MasterBook/JavaScript_SectionPage/JavaScript_SectionPage.htm), which is currently implemented only in a small number of (Desktop) PDF viewers. For Evince (Gnome document viewer), JavaScript support appears somewhere at the end of their [↗Roadmap](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince/Roadmap).

Comment: KDE Okular, as of April 2020, also supports `animate`-made animations.