# How can I put this .gif in one of my beamer frames?

Tags: movie15, gif

I have this link [moving.gif file](https://images.app.goo.gl/AiqfXmut7ncjbLa79)

which I downloaded in my working directory to be included in one of my beamer frame for presentation. Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{movie15}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{~}
\begin{block}{~}
    \includemovie{1cm}{1cm}{C:/Users/user/Documents/LATEX/Bootstrap.gif}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It runs successfully but does not show the Bootstrap.gif

**here is what I want**

[image: moving.gif file]

Comment: what could the issue be?

Comment: Probably related: [Getting Gif and/or moving images into a LaTeX presentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/240243/134144)

Comment: It seems as if .gif file is not supported in beamer, How do I convert my gif file to series of .png files so I can use animate package?

Comment: For example with ImageMagick as explained in the beginning of the answer to the question that I linked to in my previous comment.

Comment: \documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}{Embedded Animation}
  \animategraphics[loop,controls,width=\linewidth]{10}{C:/Users/user/Documents/Rplot.png}{1}{16}
 \end{frame}
\end{document}

Comment: the above is what I am running on my texstudio. I saved my .png (Rplot1, Rplot2,...,Rplor100) files in a folder which I name Rplot

Comment: Do the files Rplot1.png, Rplo2.png, ..., Rplot16.png existiert? Also remove .png from your code line.

Comment: can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: And copy all the files over to the directory with your tex document. Remove the path part Form your code line.

Comment: yes, they exist in the directory I provided, I have removed the extension, still not run

Comment: how do I set directory? I use texstudio and MiKTeX. I always put my file path like i did in my comment above. I am getting to know that i need to set the working directory for the first time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102456/discussion-between-alexg-and-daniel-james).