# Animate a sequence of png files

Tags: animations, animate

I have a `png` sequence given as the following: `Comp1-000.png`, `Comp1-001.png`, ... , `Comp1-311.png`.

How could I form an animation, probably using the package `animate`, from them?

Comment: Hi and welcome. In which format do you want this animation? `html`? `svg`? `pdf`? `gif`?

Comment: Hi! So I am using TeXWorks and want to create a pdf with an animation with the above png sequence.

Comment: Does one of the 6 answers to this question solve your problem? [Getting GIF and/or moving images into a LaTeX presentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/240243/138900)

Comment: Hmm kind of. I wrote `\animategraphics[loop,controls,width=\linewidth]{10}{Comp-}{000}{311}`, but it doesn't work. Any help? I think its due to the way that all the individual png's are numbered, because they write `\animategraphics[loop,controls,width=\linewidth]{10}{something-}{0}{16}` in their answer.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, you must write `\animategraphics[loop,controls,width=\linewidth]{30}{Comp1-}{000}{311}`