# How to embed GIF into a Beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, animations, animate, png, gif

I want to add a gif into my beamer presentation. I already converted my gif into pngs like in the picture.[image]

But I have no idea how to embed png sequence to my tex file.

I used the following code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document} 
\begin{frame}{Embedded Animation} 
  \animategraphics[controls,width=\linewidth]{10}{a-}{0}{64}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe use `\multiinclude`? See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240243/getting-gif-and-or-moving-images-into-a-latex-presentation, specifically the second answer. This is a bit more compatible with different viewers than `\animategraphics`, which only works with Adobe Reader.

Comment: @Marijn I getting error, that is, ! Package pdftex.def Error: File `a-0.png' not found: using draft setting.

Comment: Instead of `a-` use the full path to the png figures. Assuming a sub-directory  `anima` of the working directory use `./anima/a-`