# Animated Cholesky decomposition for 5x5 Matrix

Tags: animations, animate, movie15, gif

Consider this cool animated gif of a 5x5 matrix undergoing Cholesky decomposition which I found on wikipedia's article on Cholesky decomposition

[image]

The issue is that I attempted to include it in my pdf latex using the package `\movie15` in addition I used the package `hyperref` and all together consider the code :

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,lastpage}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{movie15}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\includemovie{1cm}{1cm}{Chol.gif}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately running this code gave me something well...
[image]

this fixed image that looks some ship from outer space. I have referred to other links for questions related to animated gifs in LaTeX and I have not found any mistake I made. I truly hope this can be fixed so that I can spend all day starting at this gif on my beautiful LaTeX document and thank you :)

Update: I have converted this gif into 51 images with each image representing one frame using the magick software.

Update2: Now that I have decomposed the gif into 51 images I am having a hard time doing the final step which is embedding these images into an animation-supported pdf which I only know of Adobe Acrobat Pro but its not free at all. I would hope someone can guide me from here.

[image]

Comment: GIF is not supported directly. Follow these instructions:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240387

Comment: I am looking for an animation-supported pdf embedder.

Comment: Now, that you have the numbered sequence, hopefully in PNG format, strictly follow the instructions linked above and starting from item "2." You may chose any documentclass in lieu of `beamer`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \animategraphics[autoplay,loop]{1}{Chol-}{1}{50}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I ran `convert Chol.gif Chol.png` to get `Chol-1.png` through `Chol-50.png` and then complied the above tex file. The animation in the resulting pdf file work in Adobe reader.
[image]

Comment: @BEIRUT  I guess you need an Adobe reader or something better to see the animation. For instance, in MacOS, the Preview App cannot display the animation.

Comment: It worked as you mentioned. So, overall one needs to run this on adobe as you mentioned to get the animation. You have answered my question thank you!

Comment: @BEIRUT, It's basically so.