# How to embed GIF on beamer?

Tags: beamer, gif

I have recently switched to Beamer after getting some exposure to LaTeX. I was just curious about how we can incorporate GIFs and videos in a beamer presentation. Links and references to sources will work too.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting GIF and/or moving images into a LaTeX presentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240243/getting-gif-and-or-moving-images-into-a-latex-presentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beamer is a pretty useful tool for presentations. It is good that you have tried to embed GIFs. For GIFs, you can look at the `animate` package. [This](http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf) should be a good place to start. Also note that Beamer does not allow you to directly embed GIFs. There is a neat trick of splitting a GIF to several images and then animating them. If you use Linux you can install `ImageMagick`. Refer [this](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) for ImageMagick.