# How to include a GIF image in a title frame in latex beamer

Tags: beamer, gif, frame

I am using the following beamer theme:
https://www.overleaf.com/project/626927e775988aa7abc79c3f

Instead of having the image "library.jpg" in the title frame, is there a way that I can replace it with a GIF image? I am aware of how GIFs are inserted in Latex beamer, but I don't seem to figure out how to insert it in a title fram. If anyone can help.

Comment: Welcome! Most people cannot see your example, as they do not have an Overleaf account. Please add a minimal compilable example, one that starts with `\documentclass...` and ends with `\end{document}`. You can insert formatted code directly into your question. "Minimal" means restrict its content to the bare minimum to demonstrate your issue.

Comment: Latex does  not support gif, so I'd like to know how you'd include a gif in general

Comment: @daleif : not directly, but https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240387

Comment: @AlexG that's cheating. And I'd never recommend users to rely on only fly conversion

Comment: You overleaf link says "Restricted, sorry you don’t have permission to load this page." :(