# How to insert gif-file or short video in lylualatex?

Tags: video, lilypond, gif

I am working on an essay about music playing. So I decided to use lylualatex.
That way I can integrate lylipond examples into my text. Took some time, but works fine now. The files are processed by lualatex.
For readers on tablet/computer etcetera I also want to embed short gif-files (and if that is impossible) videofiles, to demonstrate certain movements/gestures.

How to achieve this? Regards, Eef Weenink

Comment: I guess lylualatex is just an extended TeX format producing PDF output? Then, for embedding an animated image sequence you could try this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240387 Note that GIF is not supported by the PDF format specification. That is why it must be split first into an image file sequence, preferably in PNG format, as described in the linked topic. Also note that PDF viewers and ebook readers on mobile devices generally do not display animated content. Acrobat Reader or Okular (Linux) on PCs can be used.

Comment: And note that Acrobat Reader isn't good at displaying embedded video files anymore since it has abandoned Flash support.

Comment: lylualatex is specially made to show snippets of musical score in Tex.doc. 
Thanks @AlexG. Inspires me to maybe use some splitted png’s to show a movement in 4-5 small images + hyperlink to video on YouTube.