# How to insert gif animation in beamer presentation latex?

Tags: beamer, graphics, presentations, animations, gif

I've searched here this question, but the options I found was not useful.
I need to insert gif figure in beamer presentation.
To be more precisely, I need to insert this animation I found in Wikipedia, which I downloaded:

[Animation Tautochrone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautochrone_curve#/media/File:Tautochrone_curve.gif)

I have used this below:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{animate} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{frame}{Embedded Animation} 
\animategraphics[loop,controls,width=\linewidth]{10}{something-}{0}{16}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

I replaced the word "something" by the name of my gif which is "tauto" (this figure I saved in the same folder as the beamer). But is appearing a message of error which is: **File `zref-abspage.sty not found. ^^M**

Comment: Click on the [gif] tag below your question and than open the now second question in the list sorted by activity ;-).

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240243/getting-gif-and-or-moving-images-into-a-latex-presentation @AlexG this one? Did not work for me.

Comment: Yes. At which step did you get stuck?

Comment: \documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Embedded Animation}
  \animategraphics[loop,controls,width=\linewidth]{10}{something-}{0}{16}
\end{frame}
\end{document} 

I've used this hint above. I replaced the word "something" by the name of my gif which is "tauto" (this figure I saved in the same folder as the beamer). But is appearing a message of error which is:"File `zref-abspage.sty' not found. ^^M"

Comment: Your TeX installation seems to be incomplete, if `zref-abspage.sty` is missing.