# onslide and overprint: manual animation

Tags: beamer, overlays, animations

I am on a mac using Preview, so the [gif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/240243/144086) approach doesn't work for me when animating images in `beamer`.
Instead, I am using `\onslide<>` and `\includegraphics`.
Since I have 10+ images, I was wondering if there is a more general way to do the following:

```
\begin{overprint}
      \onslide<2>\resizebox{0.5\linewidth}{!}{\includegraphics{fig-0}}%
      \onslide<3>\resizebox{0.5\linewidth}{!}{\includegraphics{fig-1}}%
      \onslide<4>\resizebox{0.5\linewidth}{!}{\includegraphics{fig-2}}%
      \onslide<5>\resizebox{0.5\linewidth}{!}{\includegraphics{fig-3}}%
      \onslide<6>\resizebox{0.5\linewidth}{!}{\includegraphics{fig-4}}%
      \onslide<7>\resizebox{0.5\linewidth}{!}{\includegraphics{fig-5}}%
      \onslide<8>\resizebox{0.5\linewidth}{!}{\includegraphics{fig-6}}%
      \onslide<9>\resizebox{0.5\linewidth}{!}{\includegraphics{fig-7}}%
      \onslide<10>\resizebox{0.5\linewidth}{!}{\includegraphics{fig-8}}%
      \onslide<11>\resizebox{0.5\linewidth}{!}{\includegraphics{fig-9}}%
      \onslide<12>\resizebox{0.5\linewidth}{!}{\includegraphics{fig-10}}%
\end{overprint}
```

In particular, I would like to avoid specifying the exact frame number (in case I add some more animations preceding this one on the same slide).

---

EDIT: solved by @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

```
\usepackage{xmpmulti}
...
\transduration<0-11>{0}
\multiinclude[<+->][format=png, graphics={width=\linewidth}]{fig}
```

Comment: You could use `\multiinclude` to automatically include a bunch of images, see my example from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240247/36296 That's basically the same approach you are using, just with a convenient macro.